# DateTime to string, in F#, can this be optimized further?

Tags: optimization, f#

I have a system that does some simulations and outputs a lot of log information with timestamps.

I was surprised to see that DateTime.ToString() was quite expensive in the loop (it's really called a lot), so I tried to make a much faster version that outputs the date, time, and milliseconds.

Can this be done faster (the output needs to have milliseconds)? I didn't try to use a pointer because I assumed (maybe wrongly) that for such a small piece of code, the overhead of pinning the object would be higher.

```
module DateTimeFormatter =

    let inline private valueToDigit (value: int) : char =
        char (value + int '0')

    let inline private write2Characters (c: char[]) offset value =
        c.[offset + 0] <- valueToDigit (value / 10)
        c.[offset + 1] <- valueToDigit (value % 10)

    let inline private write3Characters (c: char[]) offset value =
        c.[offset + 0] <- valueToDigit (value / 100)
        c.[offset + 1] <- valueToDigit ((value % 100) / 10)
        c.[offset + 2] <- valueToDigit (value % 10)

    let format (dateTime: DateTime) =
        let c = Array.zeroCreate<char> 23
        write2Characters c 0 (dateTime.Year / 100)
        write2Characters c 2 (dateTime.Year % 100)
        c.[4] <- '-'
        write2Characters c 5 dateTime.Month
        c.[7] <- '-'
        write2Characters c 8 dateTime.Day
        c.[10] <- ' '
        write2Characters c 11 dateTime.Hour
        c.[13] <- ':'
        write2Characters c 14 dateTime.Minute
        c.[16] <- ':'
        write2Characters c 17 dateTime.Second
        c.[19] <- '.'
        write3Characters c 20 dateTime.Millisecond

        new string(c)
```

Here is the test code:

```
let a = DateTime.UtcNow
let iterations = 10_000_000
let sw = Stopwatch()

sw.Start()
for i = 0 to iterations do
    a.ToString() |> ignore
sw.Stop()
printfn $"original no ms display {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms"

sw.Reset()
sw.Start()
for i = 0 to iterations do
    a.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) |> ignore
sw.Stop()
printfn $"original with ms display {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms"

sw.Reset()
sw.Start()
for i = 0 to iterations do
    a |> DateTimeFormatter.format |> ignore
sw.Stop()
printfn $"new with ms display {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms"
```

and the test results (MBP i7 2019):

```
original no ms display   2892 ms

original with ms display 4042 ms
new with ms display      1435 ms
```

Comment: Depending on whether the formatting function needs to be thread safe: did you measure reusing the array (and setting the constant chars only once)?

Comment: I didn't think of that. A string gets created from the array, but then it's embedded in another string, so, by then, the array can probably be wiped out. Good idea, I will try that!

Comment: @CaringDev, I just took the array init out of the method and made it part of the module and the performance dropped by 13% no clue why!

Comment: There might be some checks for static initialization... what if you move it only outside of the loop?

Comment: In the end... need to check in the real context anyway. These micro-optimizations tend to be very fragile :-)

Comment: I just tried to create the buffer outside of the format call and pass it as a parameter, it runs 11% faster! ideally I need to find a way to keep that buffer in the same module.

Comment: Make sure your `DateTimeFormatter.format` function is giving the output you expect. For instance, you might need it to call `String c` at the end instead of `string(c)` to get the expected string value.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson, what would be the difference here? one does a cast and the other one calls a method, right?

Comment: When I called this with `string(c)` I got `**** date = System.Char[]` not the expected string:
for i = 0 to iterations do
    let d = a |> DateTimeFormatter.format
    if i = 0 then printfn $"**** date = %s{d}"

Comment: ahh, ok, I see; thanks for pointing this, I will have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I would improve

- Avoid re-creating char array
- Avoid re-assigning delimiters in char array - they never change
- Avoid re-assigning part of the date that didn't change. If you worry about milliseconds, I would assume that years, months, days, hours, minutes, and even seconds don't change very often.
- Avoid re-calculating the value of `int '0'` - it never changes
- Avoid additional function calls

  ```
  let format =
       let mutable year = -1
       let mutable month = -1
       let mutable day = -1
       let mutable hour = -1
       let mutable minute = -1
       let mutable second = -1
       let array = "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000".ToCharArray()
       let zeroChar = int '0'

       fun (dateTime: DateTime) ->
           if dateTime.Year <> year then
               year <- dateTime.Year
               array.[0] <- char (zeroChar + year / 1000)
               array.[1] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 1000) / 100)
               array.[2] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 100) / 10)
               array.[3] <- char (zeroChar + (year % 10))

           if dateTime.Month <> month then
               month <- dateTime.Month
               array.[5] <- char (zeroChar + month / 10)
               array.[6] <- char (zeroChar + month % 10)

           if dateTime.Day <> day then
               day <- dateTime.Day
               array.[8] <- char (zeroChar + day / 10)
               array.[9] <- char (zeroChar + day % 10)

           if dateTime.Hour <> hour then
               hour <- dateTime.Hour
               array.[11] <- char (zeroChar + hour / 10)
               array.[12] <- char (zeroChar + hour % 10)

           if dateTime.Minute <> minute then
               minute <- dateTime.Minute
               array.[14] <- char (zeroChar + minute / 10)
               array.[15] <- char (zeroChar + minute % 10)

           if dateTime.Second <> second then
               second <- dateTime.Second
               array.[17] <- char (zeroChar + second / 10)
               array.[18] <- char (zeroChar + second % 10)

           let ms = dateTime.Millisecond
           array.[20] <- char (zeroChar + ms / 100)
           array.[21] <- char (zeroChar + (ms % 100) / 10)
           array.[22] <- char (zeroChar + ms % 10)

           new string(array)
  ```

Running it with your test case shows x2 performance against your solution and x5 comparing to the original.

```
original no ms display 2354 ms
original with ms display 3545 ms
new with ms display 1221 ms
newest with ms display 691 ms
```

Further optimization could be avoiding DateTime property calls and calculate values manually depending on Ticks.

Comment: very good! I use sparse data where dates may span across many days with nothing happening and then 20 things happen in one second :) but I can definitely write the year once. I made the assumption that things like "int '0'" would be evaluated a single time by the compiler (like it would in C++ for example). It's not the case with .net?

Comment: @Thomas it *might* be optimized at runtime by JIT (noone knows) but it will definitely be in compiled as `ldc.i4.s 48` and `conv.i4` instructions

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the array and not rewriting the constant characters have already been mentioned in the comments. Further considerations:

- Use of the `inline` keyword here does not seem to affect compiler optimizations of "inlining" the corresponding expressions; that objective could be served better by avoidance of arithmetic operations on the array indices
- Calls to the `System.DateTime` property getters seem to be expensive
- The return value is generated by a call to a constructor of the type `System.String`, for which `new string(c)` is the C# way of calling it

Therefore, have a look at this - the additional divisions by 1 do not seem to slow it down:

```
let internal c = "0000-00-00T00:00:00.000".ToCharArray()
let internal (%&) x m = char(48 + (x / m) % 10)
let format (a : System.DateTime) =
    let y, m, d, h, min, s, ms =
        a.Year, a.Month, a.Day,
        a.Hour, a.Minute, a.Second,
        a.Millisecond
    c.[ 0] <- y   %& 1000
    c.[ 1] <- y   %& 100
    c.[ 2] <- y   %& 10
    c.[ 3] <- y   %& 1
    c.[ 5] <- m   %& 10
    c.[ 6] <- m   %& 1
    c.[ 8] <- d   %& 10
    c.[ 9] <- d   %& 1
    c.[11] <- h   %& 10
    c.[12] <- h   %& 1
    c.[14] <- min %& 10
    c.[15] <- min %& 1
    c.[17] <- s   %& 10
    c.[18] <- s   %& 1
    c.[20] <- ms  %& 100
    c.[21] <- ms  %& 10
    c.[22] <- ms  %& 1
    System.String c
```

This will hopefully be compiled into the following C# code:

```
public static string format(DateTime a)
{
    int year = a.Year;
    ...
    c[0] = (char)(48 + year / 1000 % 10);
    c[1] = (char)(48 + year / 100 % 10);
    c[2] = (char)(48 + year / 10 % 10);
    c[3] = (char)(48 + year / 1 % 10);
    ...
    return new string(c);
}
```